# JSON Convert Deserialize Object

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, deserialization

I have an issue with my JSON to XML code. It's not assigning the values to the Object and I cannot figure out why. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

My C# code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;

namespace JSONTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "C:\\Code\\JSONTest\\data\\response.xml";

            // Convert XML Data into JSON Data
            XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
            xmlFile.Load(fileName);
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlFile);

            // Convert JSON Data into Object
            RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
            var data = root.RESPONSE_GROUP;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public RESPONSEGROUP RESPONSE_GROUP { get; set; }
        }

        public class RESPONSEGROUP
        {
            public string MISMOVersionID { get; set; }
            public object RESPONDING_PARTY { get; set; }
            public object RESPOND_TO_PARTY { get; set; }
            public RESPONSE RESPONSE { get; set; }
        }

        public class RESPONSE
        {
            public string ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
            public KEY KEY { get; set; }
            public STATUS STATUS { get; set; }
        }

        public class KEY
        {
            public string _Name { get; set; }
            public string _Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class STATUS
        {
            public string _Code { get; set; }
            public string _Condition { get; set; }
            public string _Description { get; set; }
            public string _Name { get; set; }
        }
}
```

XML

```
<RESPONSE_GROUP MISMOVersionID="2.4">
    <RESPONDING_PARTY/>
    <RESPOND_TO_PARTY/>
    <RESPONSE ResponseDateTime="2015-02-19T10:32:11-06:00">
        <KEY _Name="LOSClientID" _Value="3000799866"/>
        <STATUS _Code="S0010" _Condition="Success" _Description="TEST DESC" _Name="Complete"/>
    </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSE_GROUP>
```

My "JSONData" string:

```
{"RESPONSE_GROUP":{"@MISMOVersionID":"2.4","RESPONDING_PARTY":null,"RESPOND_TO_PARTY":null,"RESPONSE":{"@ResponseDateTime":"2015-02-19T10:32:11-06:00","KEY":{"@_Name":"LOSClientID","@_Value":"3000799866"},"STATUS":{"@_Code":"S0010","@_Condition":"Success","@_Description":"THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION.","@_Name":"Complete"}}}}
```

The value of: `root.RESPONSE_GROUP.MISMOVersionID` is `NULL` as well as any other values that should have been populated.  I know I'm doing something wrong here, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Please help!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since there are two levels of conversion here, you're probably also going to have to supply the XML for us to help.

Comment: Your JSON has a property called `@MISMOVersionID`. Your actual property is `MISMOVersionID`. (Ditto for ResponseDateTime, _Name etc.)  I'm not sure I'd *expect* that to work....

Comment: @CharlieKilian -  The JSON data I provided is equal to `jsonData`.  However, I'll provide the XML since you requested it.

Comment: @Turp: If the XML is irrelevant (which it sounds like it might be) then why not remove it from your sample code? If you could further reduce your sample JSON and class hierarchy, that would be good too.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I added the XML.  It might help with showing the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON contains `@` signs in front of some property names. For example:

```
"@MISMOVersionID":"2.4"
```

There are two options here:

- Fix the JSON to *not* have that, e.g. `"@MISMOVersionID":"2.4"`
- Use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to tell Json.NET which property name to expect in the JSON, e.g.

  ```
  [JsonProperty("@MISMOVersionID")]
  public string MISMOVersionID { get; set; }
  ```

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you, Jon!